# spark - how to extract hour from timestamp?

Tags: apache-spark, datetime

Please help understand why the `date_format` does not extract `08:15` for **8:15am**?

```
spark.sql("select date_format(date '1994-11-05T08:15:30-05:00', 'hh:mm') AS hour_in_day_number").show()

+------------------+
|hour_in_day_number|
+------------------+
|             12:00|
+------------------+
```

```
spark.sql("select date_format(date '1994-11-05T08:15:30-05:00', 'HH:mm') AS hour_in_day_number").show()

+------------------+
|hour_in_day_number|
+------------------+
|             00:00|
+------------------+
```

```
spark.sql("select date_format(date '1994-11-05T08:15:30-05:00', 'kk:mm') AS hour_in_day_number").show()

+------------------+
|hour_in_day_number|
+------------------+
|             24:00|
+------------------+
```

[W3C Date and Time Formats](https://www.w3.org/TR/NOTE-datetime)

> Examples
> 1994-11-05T08:15:30-05:00 corresponds to November 5, 1994, 8:15:30 am, US Eastern Standard Time.

[Datetime Patterns for Formatting and Parsing](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-ref-datetime-pattern.html)

| Symbol | Meaning | Presentation | Examples |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| G | era | text | AD; Anno Domini |
| y | year | year | 2020; 20 |
| D | day-of-year | number(3) | 189 |
| M/L | month-of-year | month | 7; 07; Jul; July |
| d | day-of-month | number(3) | 28 |
| Q/q | quarter-of-year | number/text | 3; 03; Q3; 3rd quarter |
| E | day-of-week | text | Tue; Tuesday |
| F | aligned day of week in month | number(1) | 3 |
| a | am-pm-of-day | am-pm | PM |
| h | clock-hour-of-am-pm (1-12) | number(2) | 12 |
| K | hour-of-am-pm (0-11) | number(2) | 0 |
| k | clock-hour-of-day (1-24) | number(2) | 0 |
| H | hour-of-day (0-23) | number(2) | 0 |
| m | minute-of-hour | number(2) | 30 |
| s | second-of-minute | number(2) | 55 |
| S | fraction-of-second | fraction | 978 |
| V | time-zone ID | zone-id | America/Los_Angeles; Z; -08:30 |
| z | time-zone name | zone-name | Pacific Standard Time; PST |
| O | localized zone-offset | offset-O | GMT+8; GMT+08:00; UTC-08:00; |
| X | zone-offset ‘Z’ for zero | offset-X | Z; -08; -0830; -08:30; -083015; -08:30:15; |
| x | zone-offset | offset-x | +0000; -08; -0830; -08:30; -083015; -08:30:15; |
| Z | zone-offset | offset-Z | +0000; -0800; -08:00; |

## Environment

```
$ spark-submit --version
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 3.1.2
      /_/
                        
Using Scala version 2.12.10, OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, 1.8.0_312
Branch HEAD
Compiled by user centos on 2021-05-24T04:27:48Z
Revision de351e30a90dd988b133b3d00fa6218bfcaba8b8
Url https://github.com/apache/spark
Type --help for more information.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used `date`, which only keep year, month and day.

You can try use `tiemstamp` as below:

```
scala> spark.sql("select date_format(timestamp '1994-11-05T08:15:30-05:00', 'hh:mm') AS hour_in_day_number").show()
+------------------+
|hour_in_day_number|
+------------------+
|             05:15|
+------------------+
```

You can refer https://databricks.com/blog/2020/07/22/a-comprehensive-look-at-dates-and-timestamps-in-apache-spark-3-0.html